# open and print a file from a specific application

Tags: powershell

As I have no experience in powershell i need your assistance. I want to open a file from an application, print the file and close the application. This is what I have tried so far:

Invoke-Item $filelocation `$filelocation = 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\RSView Enterprise\SE\HMI Projects\printer\DLGLOG\print\2021 10 30 0000 (Float).DAT' Invoke-Item $filelocation` 
what I did is make the application the default application for DAT files and I can open the file directly. I have also tried the Out-Printer but with no luck. Does anyone know what commands should I use to simulate the mouse click on Print and then the OK button?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Your best bet is to determine if your application has a CLI that would allow you both pass a document path _and_ request printing it, or to see if it has an API that would allow you to do the same. GUI scripting (simulating user input) is always brittle and should be a last resort.

Comment: What is the application you are using for the DAT file? Does "CTRL+P" bring up the print dialog? If not, is there another keyboard shortcut for that?